# thrift binary type in python (read a binary file and pass it to thrift)

Tags: python, erlang, thrift

Hi I have a python thrift client and a erlang thrift server. The python client needs to read a binary file and send file content as a binary type to the erlang server.
I did

file=("filename","rb")

binarycontent=file.read()

but when I send the variable "binarycontent" to the thrift server, I got {thrift_socket_server,244,{child_error,function_clause,[]}} error
Also, if I do type(binarycontent), it says it's a string.

My question is there a type called binary in python or how should I send this binary content to the server side?

Comment: It's hard to comment helpfully without code samples from you. Could you provide some?

Comment: This question (and its answer) could be similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494031/thrift-python-server-erlang-client-errors-thrift-socket-server-244-child).  At least, the reported error message is the same.  If in doubt about how to talk to the thrift server, consult the code provided there.

Comment: It's normal that `type(binarycontent)` returns `str`.  The `File.read` method reads a file's contents and returns them in a string, whether the reading mode is text or binary.